# Merging array to a string but stop at an integer value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Making a discord bot and trying to make a command that creates voice channels.
So as an input you have the prefix, command name, channel name, and optional channel limit.
When I make the channel I have to take the string arguments and merge them, setting that as the channel name.
My problem is how to merge the arguments up till the integer value and not include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply keep going until you meet a number:

```js
const args = ['some', 'args', 'here', 5, 'different', 'args'];

let channelName = '';
for (const arg of args) {
  if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(arg, 10))) break;
  channelName += ' '; // space to separate the arguments
  channelName += arg;
}
channelName = channelName.trim(); // get rid of leading/trailing whitespace
console.log('channelName', channelName);

// or using a numeric loop, allowing you to start at e.g. position 1
channelName = '';
for (let i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
  if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(args[i], 10))) break;
  channelName += ' '; // space to separate the arguments
  channelName += args[i];
}
channelName = channelName.trim(); // get rid of leading/trailing whitespace
console.log('channelName', channelName);
```

I'm using`Number.isInteger(parseInt('string', 10))` to check whether the string can be converted to an integer. Make sure to add the `, 10`, otherwise `parseInt` will also parse e.g. `0x40` even though that might not be what you want.